# Finding sub-array sum in an integer array

Tags: algorithm, arrays

Given an array of N positive integers. It can have `n*(n+1)/2` sub-arrays including single element sub-arrays. Each sub-array has a sum `S`. Find `S's` for all sub-arrays is obviously `O(n^2)` as number of sub-arrays are `O(n^2)`. Many sums `S's` may be repeated also. Is there any way to find count of all distinct sum (not the exact values of sums but only count) in `O(n logn)`.

I tried an approach but stuck on the way. I iterated the array from index 1 to n.
Say `a[i]` is the given array. For each index `i`, `a[i]` will add to all the sums in which `a[i-1]` is involved and will include itself also as individual element. But duplicate will emerge if among sums in which `a[i-1]` is involved, the difference of two sums is `a[i]`. I mean that, say sums `Sp` and `Sq` end up at `a[i-1]` and difference of both is `a[i]`. Then `Sp + a[i]` equals `Sq`, giving `Sq` as a duplicate.

Say `C[i]` is count of the distinct sums in which end up at `a[i]`.
So `C[i] = C[i-1] + 1 - numbers of pairs of sums in which a[i-1] is involved whose difference is a[i]`.

But problem is to find the part of number of pairs in `O(log n)`. Please give me some hint about this or if I am on wrong way and completely different approach is required problem point that out.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting problem. Everything I'm coming up with potentially requires considering all pairs of input elements, which is O(n^2). My gut says it's impossible.

Comment: I have been assured by one who gave me the problem that O(n logn) exists. I spent whole day thinking.

Comment: If you're still stuck tomorrow, ask him for a timeable demo, so you know he's not messing with you.

Comment: Restriction is there from that only I concluded O(n logn). Sum of elements of array is S and number of elements is N, then N*S < 10^10 is the only restriction.
If each element is having minimum value 1, then S = N, giving maximum value of N = 10^5. To pass this value in 1 s require algorithm to be O(n logn).

Comment: @user2011120: The restriction sounds very important. Is this an online judge problem? What is the source? Just a person to person explanation? :)

Comment: What does it mean when you write that an array has sub-arrays? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @mzedeler: By a substring/subarray one typically means a "slice" of the array, that is the sequence `[A[l], A[l+1], ..., A[r]]` for integers `l <= r`. That is consistent with the number of different pairs `(l,r)`, `n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: Problem is this much only. Finding count of distinct sum of all sub-arrays with restriction given above.

Comment: What I am currently trying to find is that given an array, and a number K, how to store elements of array in some structure so that we can find number of pairs whose difference is K in log n

Comment: @user2011120: I think the structure you describe does not exist for general integers. What can be noted about the problem though is that the number of distinct numbers in the array is at most ~2700, so an algorithm quadratic in that number could work (I don't see how that algorithm would look like, obviously)

Comment: It's a complicated problem. How would the algorithm look like if the array was sorted? Maybe that could provide an insight into how the general algorithm could be. Another obvious thing to note is that the trivial subarray N has a distinct sum. If there is some way that given N as a starting point one could break it down into similar problems... I keep thinking of quick sort here because of the pivot element approach.

Comment: The fastest method I can think of to actually calculate it is a variant of merge sort.  initial list is {0, A[0]}.  merge is list and list + A[1], entering only one entry as entries are duplicated.  This could be optimized using bitfields, but it's still O(N*M) where N is number of array elements and M is number of unique summations (which is O(2^N) in the worst case (think powers of two)).  Ugly.  It's interesting, but I agree that it seems any solution at least requires computing the difference in every input pair, which is O(N^2).

Comment: @all This is an active programming contest question. Please do not answer this. http://www.codechef.com/JULY13/problems/FARASA

Comment: **Flaggers:** We are aware that this is an [ongoing Code Chef challenge](http://www.codechef.com/JULY13/problems/FARASA). While this question may violate the spirit of the challenge, it does not violate the rules of Stack Overflow and does not warrant deletion. Please do not keep flagging it for deletion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When S is not too large, we can count the distinct sums with one (fast) polynomial multiplication. When S is larger, N is hopefully small enough to use a quadratic algorithm.

Let x_1, x_2, ..., x_n be the array elements. Let y_0 = 0 and y_i = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_i. Let P(z) = z^{y_0} + z^{y_1} + ... + z^{y_n}. Compute the product of polynomials P(z) * P(z^{-1}); the coefficient of z^k with k > 0 is nonzero if and only if k is a sub-array sum, so we just have to read off the number of nonzero coefficients of positive powers. The powers of z, moreover, range from -S to S, so the multiplication takes time on the order of S log S.

Comment: This answer has been up long enough that it would be unfair to remove it now. Please don't vandalize it.

Comment: @David Few people are trying hard to get problem removed but moderators are ignoring them. Its one of the decisive problem of the contest. I am not accepting it to not give anyone hint of it. Can you please delete the solution now and re-post after contest is over. I will mark it accepted thereafter.

Comment: @user2011120: We're not ignoring them - you can see the comment above. We're just *refusing* them. Neither David nor others are obligated to remove their answers, nor are we to remove your question. You will have to take responsibility for your own actions; do not try to eschew this responsibility onto others. That is just selfish and unfair.

Comment: After knowing that its live competition question. My responsibility becomes to get it removed to keep spirit of competition. I tried everything to remove it. Since deletion is not under my control. So what most I can do is to request the replier.

Comment: "Compute the product of polynomials P(z) * P(z^{-1})".  Well, I'm a little confused, but aren't there N elements in P()?  Computing the product would be N^2 right?

Comment: @Speed8ump z * z^{-1} = 1, so there's only 2*N-1 coefficients.

Comment: Consider {1, 2, 4, 8}. Possible sums are {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15}.  N=4, number of sums = (N+1)N/2.  Don't you have to visit each one?

Comment: @Speed8ump Oh, we have to visit min(2*S-1, (N+1)*N/2) of them. This algorithm is for when S <<< N^2.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the sub-arrays as a kind of tree. In the sense that subarray `[0,3]` can be divided to `[0,1]` and `[2,3]`.

So build up a tree, where nodes are defined by length of the subarray and it's staring offset in the original array, and whenever you compute a subarray, store the result in this tree.

When computing a sub-array, you can check this tree for existing pre-computed values.

Also, when dividing, parts of the array can be computed on different CPU cores, if that matters.

This solution assumes that you don't need all values at once, rather ad-hoc.
For the former, there could be some smarter solution.

Also, I assume that we're talking about counts of elements in 10000's and more. Otherwise, such work is a nice excercise but has not much of a practical value.