# PHP: Find the "best fit"

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I need the `$quantities` to fit in the `$sections` so none of the quanities are left over.

Also *product_id 1* can't be together with *product_id 2* in the same section.

The `$quantities` volume sum is always equal or smaller than the `$sections` volume sum.

The `$sections` and `$quantities` array is currently ordered by *volume* going from lowest to highest. But that can be changed if your solutions requires it to be changed.

I've tried looping each section with one quantity at a time but that results in the first quantity going in the first 4 sections so the sections volume is 14000 but the quantity in them is 13000.

```
$quantities = array(
    0 => array(
        'volume' => '13000',
        'product_id' => '2'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'volume' => '24000',
        'product_id' => '1'
    )
);


$sections = array(
    44 => array(
        'id' => '44',
        'volume' => '2000.00'
    ),
    41 => array(
        'id' => '41',
        'volume' => '3000.00'
    ),
    45 => array(
        'id' => '45',
        'volume' => '4000.00'
    ),
    46 => array(
        'id' => '46',
        'volume' => '5000.00'
    ),
    48 => array(
        'id' => '48',
        'volume' => '5000.00'
    ),
    42 => array(
        'id' => '42',
        'volume' => '5000.00'
    ),
    43 => array(
        'id' => '43',
        'volume' => '6000.00'
    ),
    47 => array(
        'id' => '47',
        'volume' => '7000.00'
    )
);
```

For example the output should look something like this:

```
   $output = array(
        0 => array(
            'section_id' => 43,
            'volume' => 6000,
            'product_id' => 2
        ),
        1 => array(
            'section_id' => 47,
            'volume' => 7000,
            'product_id' => 2
        ),
        2 => array(
            'section_id' => '44',
            'volume' => 2000,
            'product_id' => 1
        ),
        3 => array(
            'section_id' => '41',
            'volume' => 3000,
            'product_id' => 1
        ),
        4 => array(
            'section_id' => '45',
            'volume' => 4000,
            'product_id' => 1
        ),
        5 => array(
            'section_id' => '46',
            'volume' => 5000,
            'product_id' => 1
        ),
        6 => array(
            'section_id' => '48',
            'volume' => 5000,
            'product_id' => 1
        ),
        7 => array(
            'section_id' => '42',
            'volume' => 5000,
            'product_id' => 1
        ),
    );
```

Comment: Show us, what output u expect ?

Comment: I've updated the initial post

Comment: Is it possible that the quantities will be never reached? (As having quantities for product 2 with 48000)

Comment: Then given quantities sum is always equal or smaller than the sections sum

Comment: I will assume that  `$sections` is alwasy sorted based on volume

Comment: Yes, sections array is always sorted based on volume

Comment: This looks like a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which is NP-hard and as such not easily solvable. Though, the wikipedia page will give you some algorithms to start with.

Comment: If we generalize the problem - you need to find subArrays that for each one of the quantities. You can find more info here: [finding-sub-array-sum-in-an-integer-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507411/finding-sub-array-sum-in-an-integer-array)